# If I roll two fair dice, the probability that I would get at least one 6 would be....

Tags: probability, statistics, dice

$11$ out of $36$? I got this by writing down the number of possible outcomes ($36$) and then counting how many of the pairs had a $6$ in them: $(1,6)$, $(2,6)$, $(3,6)$, $(4,6)$, $(5,6)$, $(6,6)$, $(6,5)$, $(6,4)$, $(6,3)$, $(6,2)$, $(6,1)$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes.----------------

Comment: Thank you ! Just wanted to double check :)

Comment: It's easier to calculate the probability that you roll no 6's, which is ${(\dfrac{5}{6}})^2 = 25/36$, leaving $11/36$ probability that you roll at least one.

Comment: Yes. That $11/36$ is a number every backgammon player knows very well...

Comment: Or argue that the probability of "6, non 6" is (1/6)(5/6)= 5/36,  the probability of "non 6, 6" is (5/6)(1/6)= 5/36, and the probability of two 6's is (1/6)(1/6)= 1/36 so the probability of "at least one 6" is 5/36+ 5/36+ 1/36= 11/36.

Answer (score 29):

That's right. The easier approach would be to calculate the chance of *not* rolling a $6$ - that's just $\frac56$ for the first die, and $\frac56$ for the second die, so by the product rule (as the events are independent), the probability is $\frac56 \cdot \frac56 = \frac{25}{36}$.

Then the probability of rolling a $6$ is $1$ minus the probability of *not* rolling a $6$, which we just calculated: so it is $1-\frac{25}{36}=\frac{11}{36}$.

If calculating the probability of an event *not* occurring to calculate the probability of it occurring feels weird to you, you might want to read up on **complementary events**. The idea here is that the product rule can sometimes make probabilities smaller when that wouldn't make any sense --- in our example, if you had just multiplied $\frac16 \cdot \frac16 = \frac1{36}$, then that would've been obviously wrong. This is because when we work with probability, we're dealing with quantities in the $[0,1]$ interval, so multiplication usually makes things smaller, rather than larger.

Comment: So, then is rolling one or two in two tries 20/36 a little under 60%?

Comment: How would you expand this to work out, say, the chance of getting 3 dice of the same side in 10 dice? So for example, 3 6's in 10 dice.

Answer (score 6):

Yes indeed, you've got them all. So counting them, we get $11$ of the possible $36$ outcomes of which at least one $6$  is rolled. Now simply express this probability as a fraction!

Answer (score 3):

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=chance+of+throwing+1+6%27s+with+2+dice

X = # of occurrences of 6 with 2 dice

P(X=1) = P(the first dice has 6, the second hasn't) + P(the second dice has 6, the first one hasn't) = 1/6 * 5/6 + 5/6 * 1/6 = 5/ 36 + 5/36 = 5/18 = 0.2778.

Which is also what Wolfram Alpha computes.

Then P(X=2) = 1/6 * 1/6 = 1/36.

5/18 + 1/36 = 11/36, which is indeed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The probability of rolling a certain number, can be easily calculated by listing the options available, or listing the probability of not rolling that specific number and subtracting the answer from 1. The probability of a certain event occurring is always a number between 0 and 1.

Answer (score -5):

The chance of getting a $6$ with the first dice is $1/6$ and the chance with the second dice is $1/6$ therfore the chance of getting a $6$ with either dice is $1/6 + 1/6 = 1/3$....not $11/36$!!!

Comment: You count the event $(6,6)$ twice!